# Is it bad practice to typedef a smart pointer?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

I am using smart pointers on my current project, and it seems very cumbersome to have to type long lines of code when using them.

Because I wanted my code to be cleaner and easier to follow I started typedef-ing smart pointers like such:

```
typedef std::unique_ptr<System> SystemPtr;
```

So my question is, is it bad practice to typedef a smart pointer?

Comment: I have a coworker who typedefs and abbreviates everything because he hates typing. Please don't be that person.

Comment: I don't really mind typing. But it just seems like typedef-ing a smart pointer makes the code look cleaner, I am simply unsure if I'm doing the right thing by doing so.

Comment: This kind of question is likely to solicit debate.  One thing to note is that you have used a unique pointer in that typedef, but the name does not reflect this.  Semantically, the difference between seeing `unique_ptr` and `shared_ptr` is quite important.  If you're going to do this, I suggest developing your own convention to distinguish between them.  Perhaps `SystemPtrU` and `SystemPtrS`.

Comment: Thanks :) I will keep that on mind.

Comment: Personally I would just use the whole original type for clarity. You can use the `auto` feature, for example, to reduce the amount of typing.

Comment: @paddy Considering that `unique_ptr` should be the default choice and `shared_ptr` should only be used if necessary then a reasonable naming convention might be `SystemPtr` and `SharedSystemPtr` and OP's choice is fine.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with it, but your choice of name is horrible.  Someone reading that has no clue if that is a shared pointer, a unique pointer, an intrusive reference counting com pointer, or just a raw pointer to `System`.

If you really need brevity,

```
template<class T>using up=std::unique_ptr<T>;
```

is one more character at point of use than your plan `up<System>`, and makes it more clear that this is a unique pointer, and does not require a typedef per type.  Plus it leads to puns in some cases.

Comment: I think adding a suffix to the typedef is enough to show the type of pointer it is. But you answer is clean and I don't have to worry about the typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned there is nothing syntactically incorrect about it.  I'd just like to add that having to hunt for, or rely on something like Intellisense, to easily find a definition in larger projects can be unpleasant.  Programmers rely on staying "in the zone" to do their best work.  Even something as simple as taking 60 seconds to track down a typedef can ruin the groove.

For reasons like this I feel that in situations like yours and simply in general, it's a better practice not to apply typedefs liberally.  You should be able to easily and quickly find a variable's type by traversing to the top of the associated scope.

And truth be told your type isn't that long (high level meta-types can be multiple lines long).